# Storing Data in Map Lists is Including Data from Previous List. Flutter

Tags: list, flutter

I'm having an issue with how my data is being stored in the cryptoSpots Map. I am calling the getSpotData method 3 times in the build method, each with a different passed String, like so:

```
        getSpotData('BTC');
        getSpotData('ETH');
        getSpotData('LTC');
```

The problem is that when I call getSpotData the 2nd `getSpotData('ETH')` and 3rd time `getSpotData('LTC')`, the values stored in the Lists within the cryptoSpots Map are including data from the List right before it.

For example, I want the data to be:

```
Map<String, List<FlSpot>> cryptoSpots = {
                    'BTC': [1, 2, 3],
                    'ETH': [4, 5, 6],
                    'LTC': [7, 8, 9],
                  };
```

but instead I'm getting:

```
Map<String, List<FlSpot>> cryptoSpots = {
                        'BTC': [1, 2, 3],
                        'ETH': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                        'LTC': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
                      };
```

---

```
 class Graph extends StatefulWidget {
          Graph(this.closingTimesAndPrices);
        
          final Map<String, List<dynamic>> closingTimesAndPrices;
        
          @override
          _GraphState createState() => _GraphState();
        }    
        
        class _GraphState extends State<Graph> {
              Map<String, List<FlSpot>> cryptoSpots = {
                'BTC': [],
                'ETH': [],
                'LTC': [],
              };
        
          List<double> doubleList = [];
        
          @override
          void initState() {
            super.initState();
          }
        
          getSpotData(String crypto) {
    
            // Extracting price values from Map for passed crypto and reversing it
            List<String> stringSpotsList =
                widget.closingTimesAndPrices[crypto].reversed.toList();
        
            //converting String List to Double List
            for (int j = 0; j < stringSpotsList.length; j++) {
              var doubleData = double.parse(stringSpotsList[j]);
              doubleList.add(doubleData);
            }
        
            cryptoSpots[crypto] = doubleList.asMap().entries.map((e) {
              return FlSpot(e.key.toDouble(), e.value);
            }).toList();
        
            return cryptoSpots[crypto];
          }
    }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
...(some code)...
    
        getSpotData('BTC');
        getSpotData('ETH');
        getSpotData('LTC');
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your `doubleList`  array. You are adding items to this array on every call of `getSpotData` method. That is the reason the values of previously called crypto coin are added to the current one. Instead of global `doubleList` variable you can define an another variable in your function scope or you can clear the `doubleList` array during your `getSpotData` function call.

```
...
doubleList = [];
for (int j = 0; j < stringSpotsList.length; j++) {
          var doubleData = double.parse(stringSpotsList[j]);
          doubleList.add(doubleData);
}
...
```